# How to unsubscribe from issues on drupal.org to not see the updates in my dashboard?

Tags: community-official-site

I visit My dashboard to see answers on my issues. This is comfortable.

I've been typed comments in other issues and got the answer, but now I receive the info about new comments on those issues that I do not want to look. I get the "updated" tag on them.

How to kick those issues from My Dashboard https://www.drupal.org/dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unfollow the post by clicking on following.[image]